# OpenCV Error : Assertion failed while calling detectMultiScale

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

Getting OpenCV Error : Assertion failed while calling detectMultiScale for human body detection using webcam.

Error details

> Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD9F9E5D in BodyDetection.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
>   0x00000000001AF470.
>
> OpenCV Error : Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0<= roi.width && roi.x
>   + roi.width <= m.cols && 0<= roi.y && 0<= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.roys) in cv:: Mat :: Mat, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp,
>   line 508

I'm using visual studio 2013 with x64

Comment: You should also share the section of code where you are making the function call. From the error it could be that you are calling the function with a zero sized image. Check if you are actually accessing the webcam image, e.g. by saving it in a file.

Answer (score 0):

This was mainly because of opencv files that i have installed.
32 bit and 64 bit is a tricky one!